# Why am I getting this Parameter not valid error when using this chart macro update

Tags: excel, vba, charts

```
Sub Graph_YC()
' update graph in monthly Yield Curve file using RowIndex in Col.P
Dim i As Integer
Dim RowIndex As Integer

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    For i = 1 To 6
    RowIndex = ActiveSheet.Range("P8").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i)
            .Name = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, 13)
            .Values = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(RowIndex, 2), Cells(RowIndex, 11))
            .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("$B$3:$K$3")
        End With
    Next
    
    Rows("16:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Was handed this with no VBA knowledge and told to solve it. My guess is that it has something to do with the initialization of chart object but I'm not sure. any help would be appreciated.

Code errors out at the line that says With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i). Error is invalid parameter, so I'm guessing it has something to do with the initialization of the Chart.

Comment: In the VBA IDE, putting the cursor on a keyword and pressing F1 will bring up the MS help page for that keyword.

Comment: Check the: SeriesCollection.Count if is 6, that means if the ActiveChart has 6 Series

Answer (score 1):

This would be a bit more robust.  Best to avoid using `Activate` where you can.

```vb
Sub Graph_YC()
    Dim i As Long, RowIndex As Long, cht As Chart, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set cht = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    
    For i = 1 To 6
        RowIndex = ws.Range("P8").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
        With cht.SeriesCollection(i)
            .Name = ws.Cells(RowIndex, 13)
            .Values = ws.Cells(RowIndex, 2).Resize(1, 10)
            .XValues = ws.Range("$B$3:$K$3")
        End With
    Next
    
    ws.Rows("16:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```